# 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__', can anyone help me?

Tags: python, kivy

imports:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
```

```
kv = '''

<Login>
    ben: benName.text
    pw: passwort.text
    knopf: btn
    knopff: btnn
 
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width,root.height
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: "Username"
                font_size: 25
            TextInput:
                id: benName
                multiline: False
                font_size: 30
            Label:
                text: "Password"
                font_size: 25
                bold: True
            TextInput:
                password: True
                id: passwort
                multiline: False
                font_size: 40
        Button:
            size_hint: (1.,1.10)
            text:" Start "
            id: btn
            font_size: 40
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "Readed" if passwort.text == "1" and benName.text == "1" else "login"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "down"
        Button:
            size_hint: (1.,1.10)
            text: " Exit "
            id: btnn
            font_size: 40
            on_release: app.stop()






<readed>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TextInput:
            id: text_field
        Button:
            text: 'click'
            on_press: app.read()

'''
```

`MyApp` class:

```
class Login(Screen):
    ben = StringProperty()
    pw = StringProperty()
    knopf = ObjectProperty()


class MyApp(App):
    Builder.load_string(kv)
    def read(self):
        file = open("read.txt", 'r')
        f = file.readlines()
        self.root.ids.text_field.text = (''.join(f))
        text = StringProperty("read.txt")
    def build(self):
        ms = ScreenManager()
        ms.add_widget(Login(name='login'))
        ms.add_widget(Readed(name='Readed'))
        self.title = "MyApp"
        return ms





class Readed(Screen):
    pass




if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

```
# her is the erorr
 #exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   #File "<string>", line 59, in <module>
   #File "C:\Users\---\--\Desktop\B-PYTHON\----\TEST 45.py", line 93, in read
     #self.root.ids.text_field.text = (''.join(f))
   #File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 #AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
#[Finished in 5.9s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Hello everyone, I'm making my first kivy app, a login screen with text reader input, when I press run this error message comes up I searched it in internet but couldn't find it, can anyone help me?

Comment: Please do include the full trackback error message in your question.

Comment: I inserted it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code:

```
self.root.ids.text_field.text = (''.join(f))
```

is trying to access the `ids` of the app root. But the app root is the `ScreenManager`, which has no `ids` (because it does not appear in the `kv`). That is what causes the error.

The fix is to access the `ids` of the `Readed` `Screen`, because that is where the `text_field` is defined. Try something like:

```
self.root.get_screen('Readed').ids.text_field = (''.join(f))
```

Since `root` is the `ScreenManager`, you can use `get_screen()` to get a reference to the `Readed` `Screen`. Once you have that reference, you can use the `ids` defined in the `Screen` by the `kv`.